# Android: Recyclerview inside fragment fetching data from TMDbApi gives error: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I've been struggling with a problem on android. I have an app with a drawer which shows fragments depending on what menu item you click in the drawer.

Here's how my app currently works:
This is the drawer with the menu buttons:

[image: This has 4 buttons, Movies, TvShows,Watchlist and profile]

Whenever I click a button, for instance Profile, it will load the correct Fragment: [image: Profile Fragments get loaded when I click the corresponding menu button]

Now I have this problem with the Recyclerview withing my fragmentview of TV Show

When I click on tv shows I get a white empty layout like this:

[image: Empty layout]

And this is what I get in the logcat: 
**com.example.derwishe.movielist E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**

Here's my code:

Fragment Class:

```
package com.example.derwishe.movielist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.derwishe.movielist.Api.OnGetTvShowsCallback;
import com.example.derwishe.movielist.Api.TvShow;
import com.example.derwishe.movielist.Api.TvShowsRepository;

import java.util.List;


public class TvShowFragment extends Fragment {
 private TvShowsRepository tvShowsRepository;
 private RecyclerView tvShowList;
 private ListAdapter adapter;
 Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tvshow,container,false);
    tvShowsRepository = TvShowsRepository.getInstance();
    tvShowList = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.showsRecyclerView);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    tvShowList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    this.context = context;

    tvShowsRepository.getTvShows(new OnGetTvShowsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<TvShow> tvShows) {
            adapter = new ListAdapter(tvShows);
            tvShowList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please check your internet 
connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            }
    });

    return view;
    }
}
```

Listadapter class:

```
package com.example.derwishe.movielist;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.derwishe.movielist.Api.TvShow;

import java.util.List;

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.TvShowHolder> {
private List<TvShow> tvShows;

public ListAdapter(List<TvShow> tvShows){
    this.tvShows = tvShows;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TvShowHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shows_item,parent,false);
    return new TvShowHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TvShowHolder holder, int i) {
    holder.bind(tvShows.get(i));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tvShows.size();
}

class TvShowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView showTitle;

    public TvShowHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        showTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showTitle);
    }

    public void bind(TvShow tvShow){
        showTitle.setText(tvShow.getTitle());
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity class with drawer:

```
package com.example.derwishe.movielist;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //Reference naar navigatieview voor click events

    NavigationView navigationView =findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_draw_open,R.string.navigation_draw_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    //initiele fragment openen bij start
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new MovieFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_movies);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_movies:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new MovieFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_tvshows:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new TvShowFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_watchlist:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new WatchlistFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_support:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Support message activated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

And finally the layout files:
Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/draw_menu" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_tvshow.xml which holds the recyclerview

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"


>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/showsRecyclerView"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And shows_item.xml which represents 1 item in the recyclerviewlist

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/showImage"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/showTitle"
    android:text="Show Title"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_margin="22dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because once your fragment's `onCreate` is first run, the recyclerView isn't assigned an adapter, it's until after you fetch your data (the tv shows) that you set the adapter to your recyclerView.

One way to fix this would be to have a constructor that doesn't take any arguments for your adapter, and a method inside it that would pass in whatever data the recyclerView will need to display. You'd end up with something like this:

```
public class ListAdapter {

    public ListAdapter() {}

    public void submitList(final List<TvShow> tvShows) {
        this.tvShows = tvShows;
        notifyDataChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, so I understand that when the onCreate is run that there's no adapter assigned. Now I read your answer but I think i'm not 100% getting it. I need to create an empty constructor and that method but after that? How should I use it? I'm a bit lost sorry.

Comment: can you help me whenever you got time?

Comment: Thank you , but I fixed my problem by using an Activity instead of a fragment